# Content div is over the navbar

Tags: css

So I have a navbar fixed to the top and for this I've used `position: fixed` but for some reason my content is overriding it. I would like to have something like this:

[image]

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column side" style="background-color: #aaa;">Column</div>
    <div class="column middle" style="background-color: #bbb;">Column</div>
    <div class="column side" style="background-color: #ccc;">Column</div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Codesandbox Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-dew-2g2r6?file=/index.html

Comment: put code here instead of link

Comment: Position fixed just places things on top of other content such that scrolling will always keep it on screen. Consider adding top-padding to the body equal to the height of the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some `margin-top` to the `row` class.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column side" style="background-color: #aaa;">Column</div>
    <div class="column middle" style="background-color: #bbb;">Column</div>
    <div class="column side" style="background-color: #ccc;">Column</div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to add `margin-top` css in your `row` class.

For example:

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.row{
  margin-top: 67px;
}

.footer {
   position: fixed; 
   bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>header</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column side" style="background-color: #aaa;">Column</div>
  <div class="column middle" style="background-color: #bbb;">Column</div>
  <div class="column side" style="background-color: #ccc;">Column</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

You can play with code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q2vxzbwr/1/). Also you can check here in other [resources](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp).